# If else statement is not displaying the textbox properly

Tags: arrays, angular, if-statement

I am comparing two conditions here and trying to display a textbox based on the condition.
If two dates are matching and task also same then i have to display the  time entered in the textbox from database if it is already entered, if not i need to display am empty text box. But its not working. Can any one please help me?

```js
<div *ngFor="let userTimesheet of timesheet">
    <div *ngIf="(((currentSun | date:'MM/dd/yyyy') === (userTimesheet?.task_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy')) && (user.task.task_id == userTimesheet?.task))); else notMatching " >
                <input type="text" value="{{ userTimesheet.task_totaleffort}}" formControlName="sundaytime">
    </div>
 <ng-template #notMatching>
  <input type="text" value="" formControlName="sundaytime">
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide StackBlitz for the issue?

Comment: You have a parenthesis to more than is supposed here `(user.task.task_id == userTimesheet?.task)));`. You should have just 2 closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use a ternary operator in the `input` value attribute :

```html
<div *ngFor="let userTimesheet of timesheet">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        [value]="(((currentSun | date:'MM/dd/yyyy') === (userTimesheet?.task_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy')) && (user.task.task_id == userTimesheet?.task))) 
            ? userTimesheet.task_totaleffort : ''" 
        formControlName="sundaytime">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using the ternary operator and getting the below error                                        Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in

Comment: Oh right as we use `[]` we do not need `{{}}`. I edited the answer